# Recreate a text pattern using Python

Tags: python, text

```
1010101
 10101 
  101  
   1
```

I want to recreate this pattern using Python. I am a beginner and tried many times but didn't find the answer.

Comment: What did you try? We'd like to see that so we know what commands you know and what sort of code you're familiar with

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

I see your a python beginner. Here is the code to produce a inverted triangle as it is a little complex.

```
rows = int(input("Enter number of rows: "))

for i in range(rows, 1, -1):
    for space in range(0, rows-i):
        print("  ", end="")
    for j in range(i, 2*i-1):
        print("1 ", end="")
    for j in range(1, i-1):
        print("1 ", end="")
    print()
```

This should be a bit of a hint for you to work through. now try and solve how to use the repeating 1 and 0

Answer (score 0):

```
# number of 0/1 in first line. change to any uneven number (7, 19, 217,...) 
n = 7
for i in range(n, 0, -2):
    print(" " * int((n - i) / 2), "".join(str(j % 2) for j in range(1, i+1, 1)))
```

output:

```
 1010101
  10101
   101
    1
```